# how to access payload values in mule?

Tags: database, dictionary, mule, payload

I have a mule flow and I extracted this values from a DB. I am using this value to update another db but I cant access the value. Is there something that I missed ? I tried to capture it using #[payload] and I got this

```
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: [{DELODNBLS=122, DELODNBR=1039168}]
```

but when I changed it to #[payload.DELODNBLS] it shows null values.

```
 org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: null
```

I tried changing it as an array but it still shows null values.

Thanks again gurus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the square brackets your payload is an ArrayList of Maps.

This means you need to access the record 0, this is normally the case when returning query results from db connectors in mule.
So you just need to do:

```
#[payload[0]['DELODNBLS']]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Mauro, that did it

Answer (score 1):

`#[payload[0].DELODNBLS]` will allow you to extract the value for DELODNBLS.

Answer (score 0):

your message is a collection type. You can access the value by iterating into the collection first.

```
#[payload.get(0).get('DELODNBLS')]
```